# Problem in IE 8

Tags: jquery

Hi Calling my image code refresh using following code

Here "captchaController.do" is the springController.

```
  <img name="captchaImage" id="captchaImage" src="captchaController.do" width="150px" height="30px">&nbsp;<A href="#" class="standardLink" name="refreshImage" id="refreshImage" onClick="javascript:refreshImageCode();">Refresh</A>

/* This is used to refresh the image code*/
function refreshImageCode(){
 $("#captchaImage").attr("src", "captchaController.do");
}
```

its working fine IE6 but problem in IE 8. Nothing is going happen.
Image is not displayed

Please help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? What result do you expect to see that you don't get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 is probably caching your image (or not trying to reload since the name is the same). Try this:

```
function refreshImageCode(){
    $("#captchaImage").attr("src", "captchaController.do?" + (Math.random() * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong function name. The edited code should work now.